# How can I open a project on port 4200 and use it in other machine connected on the same traffic

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have  spring-boot and angular applications that communicate with each others.
Applications are running perfectly on the server, I want to access to the angular application from another machine connected on the same traffic.
So I opened the 4200 angular port and I configured the environment api url with "ip_server:8080" , which 8080 is the backend port (spring application).
I can access to the angular application but I can't authentificate, even the backend logs don't show anything, so the request is not passed.
And in application properties for spring, I use bind address 0.0.0.0 and server port is 8080
what can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the angular app, i just changed localhost on backend api call by ipaddress of the machine and it works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).